# Lower bound for finding if graph is connected

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove that the lower bound of finding if a graph is connected is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ,or in other words the minimum amount of questions.Any suggestions how should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "questions'?

Comment: Well obviously if there are $n$ vertices $K_{n-1}$ plus a disjoint vertex makes for a disconnected graph with the maximum number of edges, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the last edge of all $\frac{n(n - 1)}2$ you are checking for existence may be either bridge or missing edge. So the answer to the question whether graph is connected may depend on the result of the last check.